# PhoneGap navigator.camera.getPicture don't trigger Callback

Tags: android, ios, cordova, camera

I have a simple Link in my PhoneGap app, which triggers following method:

```
        navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageData) {
            console.log('Success');
            $('#image').attr('src', "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData);
        }, function(errorMsg) {
            console.log('Error');
        }, {
            quality: 30,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            correctOrientation: true
        });
```

On iPhone and iPad it work's 70-80% of the time: If the user clicks, the camera opens, i take a photo, the camera is closing, the console.log() from the success-method will be triggered and i can catch the image source. The other time NOTHING happens. Either the success-, or the error-callback will be called. The camera opens, i take a photo, the camera will be closed and i see my app but nothing happens. I'm not able to find out what the problem is.

To prevent storage problems i trigger the navigator.camera.cleanup()-Method on every link-click. But the problem still exists. On iPhone, iPad and my Android Simulator. First i thought my application restarts itseft after taking the picture, but this isn't happening (i make a console.log if the deviceready-Event is happening).

I don't think it's problem from Android or iOS... But i don't know.

Answer (score -1):

make sure you call it in onDeviceReady

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady()
{
    your code here!
}
```